# Android 10: windowTranslucentStatus makes the status bar transparent

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services

Before the Android 10 update on my Huawei phone my translucent status bar used to be a transparent black bar. Since the update it's completely transparent, but I don't want this behavior. Is this a Huawei bug? If not, how can I fix this?

Comment: Forgot to mention that it works on every other device (even other Android 10 devices)

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: @mahdi Sadly not. I gave up on that one.